# How can I avoid descending certain directories with 'find'?

Tags: bash, unix, find

Currently I have this find command which avoids descending particular directories:

```
find . \! \( -name ".hg" -prune \) \! \( -name "localhost" -prune \) \! \( -name "logs" -prune \) -type f
```

The command works like I want it to, but I'm looking for a more succinct solution. I feel like I'm repeating myself a lot, and there must be a more elegant/shorter way to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

```
find . \( \( -name .hg -o -name localhost -o -name logs \) -prune \) -o -type f
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -not \( -regex ".*/(.hg|localhost|logs)" -prune \) -type f
```